# Sending XML in a SOAP using mutlipart/form-data

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui

I am starting to work with SOAP webservice that requires all requests to be POST. I don't have much SOAP/XML experience so so guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Whilst I have googled quite a lot I really cannot find anything definitive to resolve this issue.
I am using the SOAP UI tool to probe this API, however the endpoint insists that I have to have a Content-Type header as multipart/form-data in my Requests and of course the payload is a SOAP envelope

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ver="http://www.xxxxx.aa/theAPI/version3">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ver:exportUsers>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ver:login>
            <username>xxxxx</username>
            <password>yyyyy</password>
            <applicationkey>zzzzzz</applicationkey>
         </ver:login>
      </ver:exportUsers>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But this Content-Type header also requires a 'boundary' value and i am not sure what to supply

If I leave it out I get the following response message `Bad content type. please use multipart`
If I set it to \r\n for CRLF or any other variant, I get

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
X-GUploader-UploadID: BlahBlahBlahBlah
Content-Length: 44
Date: Wed, 30 Aug 2023 05:01:11 GMT
Server: UploadServer
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000

Invalid multipart request with 0 mime parts.
```

I am not sure what I can try next or the logic for sending a SOAP envelope as multipart/form-data in a POST request

Comment: My guess is that the request is expecting a SOAP envelope *and some other data*, e.g. a file you're uploading; so the SOAP envelope would be one of the "parts" of the "multipart" message, with its own content-type declared at the boundary.

Comment: A small hint: Have a look at the MTOM format, which was designed to handle multiple data formats such as plain xml together with referenced base64 encoded data which represents files in one message.

Comment: @IMSoP I am simply following the request pattern shown when the WDSL file and associated XSD are imported into SOAPUI. There is other indication that additional data is required in the Request payload..

Answer (score 0):

This error was a 'Red Herring' as further information provided by the vendor indicated. initial information led me to the wrong endpoint, which was not configured correctly, thus returning an erroneous message. Correcting the endpoint address rectified the issue with the correct expected behaviour.

As indicated by the explanation above, I can only assume that there is no logical reason or way to POST soap packets as Multipart form submission.

I am sorry to have wasted people's time chasing a very misleading error message down a rabbit hole